# getting the frame rate of a currently playing video

Tags: android, video, frame, android-videoview, rate

I was wondering - is there a way to get the frame rate at which an Android videoView is currently playing. I looked into the documentation of the VideoView class but it was to no avail. Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can.

VideoView extends View, so you'd make your own YourVideoView class which extends VideoView, implement onDraw method, call super.onDraw there, and also performing your FPS computation there.

So you can count yourself how many times in secound onDraw is called for VideoView. Display it wherever you need (on screen / logcat / ...).

Counting framerate is another story, you can look for simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930053/making-a-fps-shower).

Comment: Nope, this won't work. Turns out video is being drawn in some special way other than the other views and onDraw is being called every once in a while, but not like it should be. This work for other views, though.